# Shorttext data type uses wrong character cut-off

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with one field that is made up of hyperlinks such as this:

```
<http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Wereldkampioenschappen_indooratletiek_2008>
```

Now I have to change the datatype of this field to shorttext so I can later use JOIN in the query. From what I understand it is supposed to automatically cut-off all lines that go above the 255 character threshold. This is not the case with the example above, however if I change the datatype to ShortText it changes that text to:

```
<http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Wereldkampioenschappen_in
```

So it seems to keep only 57 characters instead of 255. I also tried using the Import Text Wizard and putting the datatype as ShortText there (so it never gets imported as a hyperlink), but the same problem persists as when I change it from hyperlink to shorttext.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks :)

P.S. I literally started working with Access today, so I'm still very much Googling everything. I couldn't find this problem anywhere though unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

`Short Text` will truncate the text to the number of characters specified in the "Table Design" view.  You can specify any number of characters from `1` to `255`.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- YouTube : [**Access 2016: Getting Started**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIVrhhEIFR8)
- Office.com : [**Access Database design basics**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5)
- Office.com : [**Introduction to data types and field properties**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c)
- Office.com : [**Data types for Access desktop databases**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/data-types-for-access-desktop-databases-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482)

Comment: I already checked that, I should've said so in the opening post! I think I fixed it. When importing the text file I chose Fixed Width instead of delimited. That fixed width was apparently set at 57 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I imported using fixed width instead of delimited. Use delimited and this problem goes away!